# How to write a TextView in a determined coordinates of the screen? (frame layout)

Tags: android, textview, android-framelayout

I have a app that shows the camera view on the screen on a **FrameLayout**. The screen is in fixed LandSape mode.

I need to write a textView with dinamically determined coordinates of the screen. The coordinates are determined in percentages, for example:

write the textview on the coorinates x=80% of the screen & y=20% of the screen.
write the textview on the coorinates x=35% of the screen & y=55% of the screen.

how to do it? i allready have the percentages, i only need to know how to use them to write the textview on the desired position of the frameLayout

code examples are welcome

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add an [AbsoluteLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html) overlay, calculate the absolute position on the screen using [screen dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions) and set the position of the view accordingly.

**Edit**

Since the AbsoluteLayout is deprecated, you can use the following technique to position the text in a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html):

```
text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams position = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

position.leftMargin = 20;
position.topMargin  = 40;

text.setLayoutParams(position);
```

Comment: absoluteLayout is deprecated :/ FrameLayout is the layout that replaces absoluteLayout, and i am allready using FrameLayout.

Comment: Huh :) You might consider just setting the margin of the view?

Comment: How can i do it? i tryed with setPadding, but it needs 4 values, i am absoluty sure that this is not the fair way to do it

Comment: Why would you need 4 values? Just set paddingLeft and paddingTop in a view overlaying the camera view (would recommend using RelativeLayout for that). I'm pretty sure it works

Comment: does not exist a setPaddingLeft method for textView... only setPadding, and needs 4 values

Comment: I think there's a leftMargin and topMargin in LayoutParams

Comment: what?, i have to put layoutParams into a textview? did you have code example for that?

Comment: ok, it doesn't works, the textview isn't repainted on the dinamically set coordinates, i tryed with: "poi.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((int)(w*(xCoordPercent/100)), h/2));"